# List.generate index null " only at Textstyle, color: " flutter

Tags: arrays, android-studio, flutter, dart, colors

I have a map of maps that stores 4 colors each and goes on like this, 1 to 20;

```
Map btncolor = {
  "1": {
    "a": Colors.grey[800],
    "b": Colors.grey[800],
    "c": Colors.grey[800],
    "d": Colors.grey[800],
  },
  "2": {
    "a": Colors.grey[300],
    "b": Colors.grey[300],
    "c": Colors.grey[300],
    "d": Colors.grey[300],
  }, [...]
```

To access it in my widget TextStyle I'm using **color: *btncolor[index][option]*,**
where option is either "a", "b" ,"c", "d" and int **index** comes from a List.generate:

I can use index in my widget everywhere to look for positions in arrays and works fine, but it gives me null if I try to use it with **btncolor** map,

> The method '[ ]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: [ ]
> (''a'')

btw trying **color: btncolor["1"][option]** works fine.

I'm not sure if we need widget code here, just tell me if needed and I will edit.
[edit]

```
  Widget choicetab(String option){
  var screen = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  var wid = screen.width;
  var hei = screen.height;

  return AbsorbPointer(
    absorbing: false,

    child: MaterialButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
      height: hei/20,
      child: Container(
        width: wid,
        //     color: Colors.red,
        child: Text(
          option+")   "+mydata[1][random_array[index].toString()][option],
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15.0,
Error here ---> color: btncolor[index.toString()][option]. <---
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () => checkanswer(option),
            ),
          );
        }
```

Comment: you can try color: btncolor["$index"][option]

Comment: same error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `index` is wrong somehow. Print out `index` value and see whether `btncolor` contains such a value or not. It's difficult to say what specifically is wrong due to a lack of the full code.

Comment: i had the noob mistake of not starting at 0, you pointed me to thanks!